# Can I have one wpf control bind to two sources?

Tags: wpf, binding

Basically I have two textboxes which binds to two columns of a `ListView`. When the user select one row in the `ListView`, the values will be displayed in the textboxes. This has no problem.

The user can edit the text of one `TextBox`, the other `TextBox` is not editable. The text of the second `TextBox` is based on the text of the first `TextBox`.  For example, the first box is product price in Chinese yuan and second box is product price in British pound. The exchange rate is from setting. The user can only edit value of Chinese yuan, but not British pound. The sold price is initially from database.

My purpose is when the user change the first `TextBox`, then in the text_changed event, I calculate the value for the second `TextBox`.

When the end user change selection to the `ListView`, It seems to me the binding to GoodsSoldPriceCN happened first, then this triggered the text_changed event. In the event handler, I calculate the sold price in pound for the second `TextBox` and this two-way binding will update source. The problem is this wouldn't update the row the user just selected, but update the row the user previously selected.

So, my question is how can I achieve this requirement.

Two textboxes bind to the selection of a row of a `ListView`.
The second text box also bind to the text of the first box when the user manually change the text of the first `TextBox`.

My code is as follows:

`XAML`

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="GoodsSoldPriceCN" Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" TextChanged="GoodsSoldPriceCN_TextChanged">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="soldpricecn" ConverterCulture="zh-cn">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ValidationRules:MoneyValueRule Min="1" Max="100000"></ValidationRules:MoneyValueRule>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>                 

<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="GoodsSoldPriceGB" IsEnabled="False"  Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}" Text="{Binding Path=soldpricegb, Converter={StaticResource MoneyValueConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ConverterCulture=en-gb}" />
```

`Code`

```
private void GoodsSoldPriceCN_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    isDirtyOrder = true;
    ListViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as ListViewItem;

    try
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(GoodsSoldPriceCN.Text))
            GoodsSoldPriceGB.Text =
            (decimal.Parse(GoodsSoldPriceCN.Text) / decimal.Parse (Properties.Settings.Default.ExchangeRate)).ToString();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }          
    }
 ...
}
```

Comment: You could achieve this by creating an attached property.

Comment: Could you give me a little bit more detail? Create an attached property in which class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Binding.SourceUpdated event instead of TextChanged event and that solve the problem.